# Codename one Face ID crashes on authentication

Tags: codenameone

I'm looking if there is any changes recently on FaceID Module, we are getting the error bellow on authentication:

```
CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called

2021-08-30 14:42:58.196592+0100 MyAPP[42960:9700283] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C2.1.1 41.137.251.15:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed

2021-08-30 14:42:58.196694+0100 MyAPP[42960:9700283] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C2.1.1 41.137.251.15:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

Comment: Which version of iOS are you using? What device? Is this working on Android etc?

Comment: Hi, it's an Iphone 11 pro max, version IOS 14.7,

Comment: From everything I'm reading, both of these errors are just log noise.  Does the app crash when you attempt authentication?  Are there any other error messages leading up to the crash?